# Ubuntu Shows Ethernet Cable Unplugged

Tags: networking, drivers, internet, ethernet

My ethernet was working until yesterday. Next day I opened the system and it shows "Cable unplugged". I am currently using Ubuntu 18.04 but I also tried my old 14.04 but no ethernet connection on that either. Although Windows 8.1 can connect to internet via ethernet. I have tried 2 different ethernet cable connected to network on different ports.

**ifconfig**

```
ens5f5: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    ether 48:5b:39:5f:f7:87  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
    device interrupt 34  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 515  bytes 77002 (77.0 KB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 515  bytes 77002 (77.0 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wls1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.43.19  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.43.255
    inet6 fe80::2ae2:dad5:808d:38ae  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 1c:4b:d6:ce:5a:27  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 3172  bytes 1975584 (1.9 MB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 3283  bytes 826575 (826.5 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

**dmesg | grep eth**

```
[    1.919044] jme: JMicron JMC2XX ethernet driver version 1.0.8
[    1.925793] jme 0000:05:00.5 eth0: JMC250 Gigabit Ethernet chiprev:23 pcirev:3 macaddr:48:5b:39:5f:f7:87
[    1.959338] jme 0000:05:00.5 ens5f5: renamed from eth0
```

**lsmod**

```
Module                  Size  Used by
rfcomm                 77824  4
ccm                    20480  9
bnep                   20480  2
nls_iso8859_1          16384  1
arc4                   16384  2
uvcvideo               86016  0
videobuf2_vmalloc      16384  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       16384  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_v4l2         24576  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_core         40960  2 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo
videodev              184320  3 videobuf2_core,videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo
media                  40960  2 videodev,uvcvideo
ath9k                 151552  0
ath9k_common           36864  1 ath9k
ath9k_hw              471040  2 ath9k_common,ath9k
ath                    28672  3 ath9k_common,ath9k,ath9k_hw
intel_powerclamp       16384  0
coretemp               16384  0
kvm_intel             212992  0
kvm                   598016  1 kvm_intel
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
pcbc                   16384  0
aesni_intel           188416  6
snd_hda_codec_conexant    24576  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    73728  1 snd_hda_codec_conexant
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     49152  1
snd_hda_intel          40960  4
snd_seq_midi           16384  0
snd_hda_codec         126976  4 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_conexant,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel
snd_hda_core           81920  5 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_conexant,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec
snd_hwdep              20480  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm                98304  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                65536  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi
lpc_ich                24576  0
joydev                 24576  0
mac80211              778240  1 ath9k
aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
crypto_simd            16384  1 aesni_intel
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 24576  3 crypto_simd,ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel
intel_cstate           20480  0
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
input_leds             16384  0
serio_raw              16384  0
cfg80211              622592  4 ath9k_common,ath9k,ath,mac80211
intel_ips              20480  0
btusb                  45056  0
btrtl                  16384  1 btusb
btbcm                  16384  1 btusb
btintel                16384  1 btusb
bluetooth             548864  31 btrtl,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb,rfcomm
jmb38x_ms              20480  0
memstick               16384  1 jmb38x_ms
ecdh_generic           24576  1 bluetooth
asus_laptop            32768  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 asus_laptop
input_polldev          16384  1 asus_laptop
mei_me                 40960  0
snd                    81920  19 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_hda_codec_conexant,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_timer,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
mac_hid                16384  0
mei                    90112  1 mei_me
soundcore              16384  1 snd
shpchp                 36864  0
sch_fq_codel           20480  2
parport_pc             36864  0
ppdev                  20480  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                49152  3 parport_pc,lp,ppdev
ip_tables              28672  0
x_tables               40960  1 ip_tables
autofs4                40960  2
hid_generic            16384  0
usbhid                 49152  0
hid                   118784  2 usbhid,hid_generic
radeon               1470464  14
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 radeon
ttm                   106496  1 radeon
drm_kms_helper        172032  1 radeon
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
ahci                   40960  3
drm                   401408  7 drm_kms_helper,radeon,ttm
libahci                32768  1 ahci
jme                    40960  0
sdhci_pci              32768  0
psmouse               147456  0
mii                    16384  1 jme
sdhci                  49152  1 sdhci_pci
video                  45056  1 asus_laptop
```

**lspci -nnk**

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Core Processor DRAM Controller [8086:0044] (rev 12)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Core Processor DRAM Controller [1043:1c77]
00:01.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Core Processor PCI Express x16 Root Port [8086:0045] (rev 12)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset HECI Controller [8086:3b64] (rev 06)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset HECI Controller [1043:1c77]
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller [8086:3b3c] (rev 06)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller [1043:1c77]
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio [8086:3b56] (rev 06)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio [1043:1643]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 1 [8086:3b42] (rev 06)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1c.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 2 [8086:3b44] (rev 06)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1c.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 3 [8086:3b46] (rev 06)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1c.5 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 6 [8086:3b4c] (rev 06)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller [8086:3b34] (rev 06)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller [1043:1c77]
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
00:1e.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge [8086:2448] (rev a6)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation HM55 Chipset LPC Interface Controller [8086:3b09] (rev 06)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. HM55 Chipset LPC Interface Controller [1043:1c77]
    Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich
    Kernel modules: lpc_ich
00:1f.2 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 4 port SATA AHCI Controller [8086:3b29] (rev 06)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 4 port SATA AHCI Controller [1043:1c77]
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset SMBus Controller [8086:3b30] (rev 06)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset SMBus Controller [1043:1c77]
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset Thermal Subsystem [8086:3b32] (rev 06)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset Thermal Subsystem [1043:1c77]
    Kernel driver in use: intel ips
    Kernel modules: intel_ips
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV710/M92 [Mobility Radeon HD 4530/4570/545v] [1002:9553]
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. RV710/M92 [Mobility Radeon HD 4530/4570/545v] [1043:1c42]
    Kernel driver in use: radeon
    Kernel modules: radeon
01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV710/730 HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 4000 series] [1002:aa38]
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. RV710/730 HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 4000 series] [1043:aa38]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) [168c:002b] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: AzureWave AW-NE785 / AW-NE785H 802.11bgn Wireless Full or Half-size Mini PCIe Card [1a3b:1089]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
    Kernel modules: ath9k
05:00.0 System peripheral [0880]: JMicron Technology Corp. SD/MMC Host Controller [197b:2382] (rev 80)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. SD/MMC Host Controller [1043:1a07]
    Kernel driver in use: sdhci-pci
    Kernel modules: sdhci_pci
05:00.2 SD Host controller [0805]: JMicron Technology Corp. Standard SD Host Controller [197b:2381] (rev 80)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Standard SD Host Controller [1043:1a07]
    Kernel modules: sdhci_pci
05:00.3 System peripheral [0880]: JMicron Technology Corp. MS Host Controller [197b:2383] (rev 80)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. MS Host Controller [1043:1a07]
    Kernel driver in use: jmb38x_ms
    Kernel modules: jmb38x_ms
05:00.4 System peripheral [0880]: JMicron Technology Corp. xD Host Controller [197b:2384] (rev 80)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. xD Host Controller [1043:1a07]
05:00.5 Ethernet controller [0200]: JMicron Technology Corp. JMC250 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [197b:0250] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. JMC250 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1043:1905]
    Kernel driver in use: jme
    Kernel modules: jme
ff:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-core Registers [8086:2c62] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-core Registers [8086:8086]
ff:00.1 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture System Address Decoder [8086:2d01] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture System Address Decoder [8086:8086]
ff:02.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Link 0 [8086:2d10] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Link 0 [8086:8086]
ff:02.1 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation 1st Generation Core i3/5/7 Processor QPI Physical 0 [8086:2d11] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation 1st Generation Core i3/5/7 Processor QPI Physical 0 [8086:8086]
ff:02.2 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation 1st Generation Core i3/5/7 Processor Reserved [8086:2d12] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation 1st Generation Core i3/5/7 Processor Reserved [8086:8086]
ff:02.3 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation 1st Generation Core i3/5/7 Processor Reserved [8086:2d13] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation 1st Generation Core i3/5/7 Processor Reserved [8086:8086]
```

Comment: Tried booting a different version/distro on a live iso?

Comment: Used different version installed already.  Not tried on live image.

Comment: If it were a software issue, a different os might work, not sure how different the other version would have to be to check though. And if the wires are good, maybe it's a port or other hardware that's bad

Answer (score 0):

I shutted down the laptop and removed the battery for 15 mins. Then it has started working.

Had a similar problem where USB did not work on a desktop computer. Shutted down and cut all electricity and it worked.